# how to get the current time by use redisson client

Tags: java, redis, redis-cluster, redisson

if i have several servers, maybe servers's current system time are different. how can i all use redisson to get current time?

I've read the RedissonClient api, but I haven't found the way to get this yet

Comment: UTC is the standard for time processing. Look for any function that gives UTC time.

Comment: ... like `java.time.ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC"));`, maybe...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a RestTemplate bean in your app, you can try this:

```
Long redisServerTimestamp = redisTemplate.execute(
                    (RedisCallback<Long>) conn -> conn.serverCommands().time());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
RedisSingle nodes = redisson.getRedisNodes(RedisNodes.SINGLE);
Time time = nodes.getInstance().time();
```